# Drupal get site wide email address?

Tags: email, drupal

In my module I want to get the site wide email address - the one that is set in the site information admin pages and that is used for all automatically send email messages.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Drupal 7

```php
$site_email = variable_get('site_mail', 'fallback@example.com');
```

### Drupal 8+

```php
$site_mail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
```

Answer (score 27):

In Drupal 8:

```
$site_mail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
```

Answer (score 17):

Looking into the [system module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module), I found the settings form references the following:

```
variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get more ideas with [this link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/7)

```
variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the variable like -

```
function hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {

  $variables['site_email'] =  \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
  //kint( $variables['site_email']);

}
```

then use  `$variables['site_email']` anywhere to get the system wide email.

Comment: It's much better to use the Drupal 8+ method of service injection than to do this.