# How can I display the site_mail in my page.tpl.php page?

Tags: php, drupal

I have tried the solution here, but it didn't work: [Drupal get site wide email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443029/drupal-get-site-wide-email-address)

Here's my code (inside page.tpl.php):

```
<a href="mailto:<?php variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from')); ?>">My name</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgotten to print the variable to the page :)

```
<a href="mailto:<?php print variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from')); ?>">My name</a>
```